# Why can't I return self in this Swift indirect enum?

Tags: swift, recursion, enums

Why can't I return `self` at the indicated point?

```swift
indirect enum BinarySearchTree<E: Comparable> {
    case leaf
    case node(BinarySearchTree<E>, E, BinarySearchTree<E>)

    mutating func insert(_ e: E) {
        switch self {
        case .leaf:
            self = .node(.leaf, e, .leaf)
        case .node(var left, let v, var right):
            if e < v { left.insert(e) }
            if e > v { right.insert(e) }
            self = .node(left, v, right)
            // Why can't I just return self here? e == v, so isn't it already a .node(left, v, right)?
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the following code, returning `self`

```swift
var bst = BinarySearchTree<Int>()
bst.insert(3)
bst.insert(5)
```

the program just stays at its initialization as

```swift
.node(leaf, 3, leaf)
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking here — are you wondering why you can't type `return self` at that spot, or why you have to re-assign to `self` via `self = .node(...)` for the code to work the way you expect? (I assume the latter, but just making sure.)

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit confused too. It seems to me that you want to mutate your tree in-place (judging by the use of `mutating`), but I'm not sure what you would want to return exactly.

Comment: Sorry, folks. Here's what I'm asking. When I reach a node whose value is equal to the inserted value, why can't I just return the existing node? The existing node is `.node(left, v, right)` and the new node is `.node(left, v, right)`. They're the same, but in fact, the code doesn't work unless I return a new node.

Comment: @Jeff I think your terminology is a bit off, because you're not actually _returning_ anything from this method (e.g., with the `return` keyword); you're _assigning_ (with `=`) back to `self`. But @HangarRash's answer should cover what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need to use `self = .node(left, v, right)` is because at that point, `self` is equal to `(.leaf, 3, .leaf)`. The local variable `right` has just been updated to `(.leaf, 5, .leaf)`.

Updating the local variable `right` does not update `self`'s `right` directly. So you need to finish off that `case` with `self = .node(left, v, right)` to update its `right` value (or its `left` value as the case may be).

You can confirm this by adding the following line after the two `if` statements:

```
print("After insert: self = \(self), right = \(right)")
```

This prints:

> After insert: self = node(__lldb_expr_53.BinarySearchTree<Swift.Int>.leaf, 3, __lldb_expr_53.BinarySearchTree<Swift.Int>.leaf), right = node(__lldb_expr_53.BinarySearchTree<Swift.Int>.leaf, 5, __lldb_expr_53.BinarySearchTree<Swift.Int>.leaf)

As you can see, `self`'s `right` has not been updated. Only the local variable `right` has been updated.

Here's a more explicit version of the `switch` statement that may make it clearer:

```
switch self {
    case .leaf:
        self = .node(.leaf, e, .leaf)
    case .node(var left, let v, var right):
        if e < v {
            left.insert(e)
            self = .node(left, v, right)
        } else if e > v {
            right.insert(e)
            self = .node(left, v, right)
        }
}
```

You don't need to do anything in when `e == v`, you only need to update `self` after updating either `left` or `right`.

Comment: The crux here is that `enum`s in Swift are _value types_, even when `indirect`, so `var left` and `var right` introduce local _copies_ of the original `left` and `right`, and so you have to reassign these updated copies back to `self`. (You cover this in your answer, but to be a bit more explicit.)

Comment: @ItaiFerber Right. That's a more explicit way to describe what I put in my answer when I stated that only the local variable is being updated.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! @ItaiFerber, that really clarified things.